# Почему сбрасываются стили css при обновлении страницы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

При открытом инспекторе кода в браузере Chrome, при добавления кода и обновлении страницы сбрасывается код css. Может ли повлиять Live server в vs code или нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы в самом инспекторе редактируете стили?

Comment: Я пишу в vs code, но когда я открываю просмотреть код в Chrome и не закрывая его. Перехожу в vs code и в style. css добавляю новое значение, то вернувшись в браузер слетают.

Comment: live server при каждом сохранении файла автоматически обновляет страницу

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пишите стили в самом инспекторе, то при обновлении страницы они и должны сбрасываться, если вы пишете в vs code, то это может быть из-за того, что live server принимает не все ссылки

Вот пример что точно работает :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Наверное траблы с LiveServer. Я полагаю что вы пытались перезапустить LiveServer.
Может поможет Ctrl + F5 (скинуть кэш страницы).